# Ply example calculator multiple expressions

Tags: python, parsing, lexer, ply

I've been trying out the Ply [example calculator from Github](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/master/example/calc/calc.py).

When I run the calculator, it runs inside of a REPL. How would I use Ply to enable multiple expressions to be evaluated, one after the other.

For example, if I enter `3+4` the REPL does this:

```
calc > 3+4
7
calc >
```

If I enter `4+3 6+2` the REPL does this:

```
calc > 4+3 6+2
Syntax error at '6'
2
calc >
```

How would I modify the example calculator to enable the REPL to do this:

```
calc > 4+3 6+2
7
8
calc >
```

Do I need to modify the grammar, the parser or both? I've tried modifying the grammar to make it left recursive but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Since the sample grammar *is already* left-recursive, your statement that you've tried modifying it to be left-recursive requires some elucidation. (And why would you think that would make a difference?)

Comment: Too broad: you've essentially found a third-party library and you're asking how to modify it for your own purposes, which is no better than "write this code for me".

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Honestly I'm not. I'm trying to write a simple interpreter using Ply and my interpreter can currently only evaluate one expression/statement at a time. I didn't want to post my interpreter since it's significantly longer than the sample calculator. I chose the sample calculator because it has the same limitation that I'm trying to figure out and it's much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample calculator's grammar allows expressions like `- 42` (or `-(4*8)+7`). If such an expression were the second expression on a line, it would create an ambiguity. Is:

```
calc > 4 * 3 -(4*8)+7
```

one expression or two?

One way to make the grammar unambiguous would be to allow multiple expressions on a line separated with a comma. You could do that by just adding `'.'` to the list of literal tokens, and placing the function

```
def p_line(p):
    '''line : statement
            | line ',' statement'''
    pass
```

as the *first* parser function (i.e., just before `p_statement_assign`.

With that change:

```
$ python calc.py
Generating LALR tables
calc > 2+3
5
calc > 2+3,4+6
5
10
calc > 2,3
2
3
calc > a=2,a+7
9
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! I never even knew you could have a line in the grammar without a parser action.

Comment: `pass` is an action. Just a very lazy one.